# Getting a refernce to an auto-instantiated Sencha Touch 2 view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs-mvc

I'd like to get a reference to my view from my Sencha Touch 2 controller, which looks like this (CoffeeScript):

```
Ext.define 'MyApp.view.Books',
    extend: 'Ext.Panel'
    id: 'books'
    config:
        html: 'Hello, Books!'
Ext.define 'MyApp.controller.Books',
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'
    views: [
        'Books'
    ]
    init: ->
        @control
            '#books':
                render: ->
                    console.log 'This is never called. Why?'
                show: ->
                    console.log 'This is called twice.'
                    # @getBooksView() is not a view instance, it is a class. Why?
                    console.log 'View class: ' + @getBooksView()?.$isClass
Ext.application
    name: 'MyApp'
    controllers: [
        'Books'
    ]
    launch: ->
        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem
            xtype: 'booksview'
```

The 'Hello, Books' content appears (e.g. the component is rendered), but the render control handler is never even called. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouln't use hardcoded `id` for any of the classes!  You should be codding your view as:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Books',{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.books',
    config: {
        html: 'Hello, Books!'
    },
    initialize : function() {   
        // some init code etc..
        this.callParent();  
    }
});
```

Note the alias property. This helps you to get the reference of your view's instances. When you refer the view. Now in your controller you have:

```
...
this.control({
    'books' : {    
        render: function() {
            console.log('Render method called!');
        },
        show: function() {
            console.log('Show method called!');
        }

    },
    .
    ...
```

Note that you are not refering your view with the id property, instead through its alias or xtype. Now, if you need to access other controller's views or any other component in your controller, you can also make use of the refs system available. In this case, you will define the refs array in the controller definition as:

```
refs: [
    {ref: 'centerPane', selector: 'centerpane'}
],
```

Here the selector property is the value passed to `Ext.ComponentQuery` to get the component. So, you can get the instance of centerpane by:

```
this.getCenterPane();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice explanation! Lately I also figured I shouldn't use ids, so I did stop using them, but I still didn't know how to get references, so I started using `name:` properties and `.down('[name=...]')`, which is obviously not how it is meant to be used. Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: I too was struggling with this, the example programs seem completely contrived and never show how you actually get hold of auto-instantiated views. Great explanation