# Sencha Touch 2 : Getting a reference to an auto-instantiated view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'd like to get a reference to a view from my controller in Sencha Touch 2. 
I followed the explanation in this question :
[Getting a refernce to an auto-instantiated Sencha Touch 2 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799747/getting-a-refernce-to-an-auto-instantiated-sencha-touch-2-view)

But still, the render and show function in this.control in my controller never get called.

This is my app.js :

```
Ext.application({

  name: 'App',
  appFolder: 'src',
  controllers: ['Home'],

  launch: function () {
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype: 'homeView'});
  }
});
```

This is my view :

```
Ext.define('App.view.HomeView', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.homeView',

    config: {
        html : ['<h1>Sencha Touch Web App</h1>']
    },

    initialize: function() {

        this.callParent();
    }

});
```

and this is my controller :

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Home', {

   extend      : 'Ext.app.Controller',
   views       : ['HomeView'],

init: function() {

   this.control({

       'homeView' : {

           render: function() {
               console.log('Render method called!');
           },
           show: function() {
               console.log('Show method called!');
           }  
        }
    })
  }
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot. 
Franziska

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` handler is not called for me either. The way I do it is either use `show`, which will be called every time the component is showed, or use a custom event for when the view is initialised, e.g.

```
Ext.define('App.view.HomeView', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.homeView',

    config: {
        html : ['<h1>Sencha Touch Web App</h1>']
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.fireEvent('render');
        this.callParent();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respone. But how do I register the event in my controller? I tried `this.addEvents`, `listeners` and `this.config`. None of it worked. Even the `show` handler still doesn't work, although it seems to work for you.Do you have a example for me?

Comment: In the controller, you should be able to do `this.control({homeView: {render: function(){console.log('rendering');}}})`

Comment: I've managed to get the render handler work. Although the show handler still doesn't get fired, it's fine for my needs. Thanks for your help.